# Creating a Maven deployment parent project

Tags: maven, deployment

I have a Maven component service that I package up as a WAR file. I would like to create another Maven project that builds a fully deployable Jetty container with a few custom configurations and contains my component service in it so that I can test my WAR or even deploy it. My questions for this scenario are:

1. Is it common to want to keep the WAR build separate from the distribution build? My thoughts behind doing this is that someone may not want to use my custom configured Jetty container. Maybe they want to create their own build with Tomcat or something else.
2. If this is a common thing to do, what packaging type should I use for the custom Jetty container project? It seems weird to me to use JAR or WAR since that isn't the actual artifact that ends up being built. And using "pom" packaging seems equally strange since I was under the impression that that is used for parent projects of submodules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ad 1. **Yes**, this is how I usually structure the project. There is an `app` project which is a container for application and a separate `deploy` project to handle the infrastructure. Regardless if it's building a container image, deploy to app server or whatsoever.

You can see it in an [example project](https://github.com/kubamarchwicki/devoxx-tools-maven/blob/master/project/) I've once created for a [Devoxx presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LsM_i-chL3k).

Ad 2. **Default packaging** (hence jar). If all you have in a project is a `pom.xml` (without any classes),  no additional jar will be created nor installed. In the project I've mentioned the [pom.xml](https://github.com/kubamarchwicki/devoxx-tools-maven/blob/master/project/deploy/docker/pom.xml) contains only docker image creation 'logic'. In your scenario it will be jetty related plugin. No additional artifacts will be created.